# How many sets of N elements can we construct by sampling with replacement N elements?

Tags: combinations, bootstrap-sampling

Assuming we have a Set of N elements and we form samples of size N by sampling with replacement the original Set, how many such samples can we construct?

Alternatively, the question is:  How many combinations of size N exist of N elements, when each element can be used more than once in a combination?

Your advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have  $N $ choices each of $N $ different times.  The choices are *independent*, so you multiply the number of possibilities, to get

> $N^N $.